# * is not a function error when creating a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

i have just started to making class in javascript, this is my first class that i have created something like:

```
function MessageBox(parent){
    this.id = "msg-box";   // ID for the Box
    this.createElements(this.id);
    this.parentElement = parent;
};
MessageBox.prototype = {
    createElements: function(id){
        // Create Main Container
        this.containerElement = document.createElement('div');
        this.containerElement.setAttribute('id', this.id);
        this.parentElement.appendChild(this.containerElement);
    }
};
```

but when i call this file in my index.html file it returns the error `createElements()` is not a function..

here is my index.html as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            var box = MessageBox('body');
            //box.start();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your function is a constructor function, you want to use

```
var box = new MessageBox('body');
//        ^^^
```

Else, no instance is created and your constructor is executed on the default context object, the global `window` object (which has no `createElements` property). Have a look at [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).